# Delphi declare Unit in Project (DPR) visible entire Solution

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

Exists the possibility for declare (uses) a UNIT in Project (.DPR or other location) and show in All Forms? (without necessary redeclare *uses* in Form the Form), a Global UNIT declarated one time in Project and visible to All Form/Units.

Answer (score 5):

No. You can't use a unit in a single place and make it visible globally. It has to be included in a `uses` clause in each unit's `interface` or `implementation` section in order to be visible in that unit. The Delphi compiler automatically makes `System` (and in recent Delphi versions `SysInit`) be included in each unit, but there's nothing that will do that for your own units.

Comment: Is `SysUtils` really auto-included now? Or maybe you [meant `SysInit` instead](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi))? "*The System unit **and the SysInit unit** are used automatically by every application and cannot be listed explicitly in the `uses` clause.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Oops! Yep, SysInit is what I meant. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you ask is not existing. But your can do something that has the same effect: use a .inc file.

Create a .inc file with the list of all common units you require. The add this include file in the uses clause of all unit.